# What is the correct way to close camera using Android Camerax API in a fragment synchronously

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I have implemented CameraX api to get camera frames using ImageAnalysis use case in a fragment. To close the camera I am using ProcessCameraProvider.unbindAll() method in fragment onPause. But this is not synchronously closing the camera. [The method declaration](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/lifecycle/ProcessCameraProvider#unbindAll()) says

> Unbinds all use cases from the lifecycle and removes them from CameraX. This will initiate a close of every currently open camera.

Is there a way to close all camera synchronously or wait until all camera get closed?

Comment: How about observing the `CameraState` from [CameraInfo#getCameraState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraInfo#getCameraState())? You can wait till the `CameraState` reports the camera is closed after calling `unbindAll()`.

Comment: @TahsinMasrur If I am waiting using while loop checking the type(OPEN, OPENING, CLOSING, CLOSE, PENDING_OPEN) of the camera state, the camera is remaining at OPEN state while loop never ends. But the logs from CameraStateRegistry shows camera state changes CLOSING and then CLOSE.

Comment: If you are using a while loop, maybe some sort of thread blocking issue? Hard to say without seeing the relevant code snippets and more details.